# Solving system of nonlinear differential equation in MAPLE

Tags: maple

I'am working out on nonlinear differential equation and I need to find the equilibrium point which means all the system is equal to zero.
Here is the System of Diferential Equation:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dS}{dt} &= \alpha - \beta SV - \delta S \\
\frac{dI}{dt} &= \beta SV - \sigma I \\
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \mu nI - \gamma_1 V - \gamma_2 V - \gamma_3 V - \beta SV
\end{align*}

then, to find the equilibrium point set $\frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{dI}{dI} = \frac{dV}{dt} = 0$. It means that I have to solve the system of equation
\begin{align*}
\alpha - \beta SV - \delta S &=0 \\
\beta SV - \sigma I &= 0\\
\mu nI - \gamma_1 V - \gamma_2 V - \gamma_3 V - \beta SV &=0
\end{align*}

I've got the result by solving it manually but Can I use MAPLE software to solve this problem?

What I've done manually:
$V = \frac{\alpha - \delta S}{\beta S}, I = \frac{\alpha - \delta S}{\sigma}, S = \frac{\alpha}{\delta} \text{ or } S = \frac{(\gamma_1 +\gamma_2+\gamma_3)\sigma}{\beta(\mu n - \sigma)} $

Comment: What result have you got?

Comment: I've made some changes to my post @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: I have solved it with Maple and now?

Comment: I will feel happy if you are willing to teach it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it in Maple

`eqs:={alpha-beta*S*V-delta*S,beta*S*V-sigma*II,`
`mu*n*II-gamma[1]*V-gamma[2]*V-gamma[3]*V-beta*S*V};`
`vars:={S,II,V};`
`solve(eqs,vars);`

Note that `I` is a reserved symbol in Maple, so I just used another symbol `II` for it.

Maple yields two solutions
$$
 \left\{ {\it II}=0,S={\frac {\alpha}{\delta}},V=0 \right\}  
$$
and
$$
 \left\{ {\it II}={\frac {\alpha\,\beta\,\mu\,n-\alpha\,\beta\,\sigma-
\delta\,\sigma\,\gamma_{{1}}-\delta\,\sigma\,\gamma_{{2}}-\delta\,
\sigma\,\gamma_{{3}}}{\beta\,\sigma\, \left( \mu\,n-\sigma \right) }},
S={\frac {\sigma\, \left( \gamma_{{1}}+\gamma_{{2}}+\gamma_{{3}}
 \right) }{\beta\, \left( \mu\,n-\sigma \right) }},  
\\
V={\frac {\alpha\,
\beta\,\mu\,n-\alpha\,\beta\,\sigma-\delta\,\sigma\,\gamma_{{1}}-
\delta\,\sigma\,\gamma_{{2}}-\delta\,\sigma\,\gamma_{{3}}}{\beta\,
\sigma\, \left( \gamma_{{1}}+\gamma_{{2}}+\gamma_{{3}} \right) }}
 \right\} 
$$